# Replacing of string using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to replace string from "_tr9-9" character from a string and replace them with _id character

Here str is changes only _tr9-0 will be changes dynamically remining will be same

```
str=Test_User_tr9-0;
```

Ex:

```
function (str)
{
   var obj=str 
}
```

Comment: In C# or JavaScript? Make your mind up...

Comment: hi david,i mentioned javascript

Comment: why did you flag it as C# then?

Comment: The string replacement function is a very basic issue in most of programming languages. Haven't you searched or tried anything before posting?

Comment: yes,i have tried,getting some issues with that.

Comment: @Liam : i.e is could you please see the question headline before answering

Answer (score 1):

You can use replace

*In javascript*

```
var str = "Test_user_tr9-9 to Test_user_id";
str = str.replace('tr9-9','id');
```

*In C#*

```
var str = "Test_user_tr9-9";
var str = str.Replace("_tr9-9", "_id");
```

Answer (score 1):

In C#

```
string str = "Test_user_tr9-9";
string str2 = str.Replace("_tr9-9", "_id");
```

In Javascript

```
var str = "Test_user_tr9-9";
var str2 = str.replace("_tr9-9", "_id");
```

Note that both in Javascript and C# strings are immutable objects, so the `replace`/`Replace` methods return a new modified string (technically in C# the `Replace` returns the original string if it doesn't find anything to replace)

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript:

```
var index = str.lastIndexOf("_");
var result = str.substring(0, index) + "_id";
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fNZkG/